# block camera rotation phonegap android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, camera

i have an app wrote with html5 and javascript.this app must be used only in portrait mode, so i used `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` . next i used phonegap to deploy it on an android device,with screen auto-rotation disabled from settings, and i've encountered a little problem. 
this app allow users to take photo. for that i'm using

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 100});
```

for some unknown reason, when i took a picture in portrait mode,system rotate in landscape mode and after the picture android try to reload my app in landscape mode, and my app crashes..

how can i block the rotation in the transition from my app to the photo app?
i tried also to set `correctOrientation:true` but it doesn't works.

fixed!!!!  put in the right place `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">` and it worked!

Comment: What is the right place? Are you kidding me?!